# What prevents my server being contactable from the internet?

Tags: linux, networking, router, debian

I have 3 devices in my home network; a Netgear ReadyNAS, a Raspberry Pi [Pi1] running Raspbian Debian and a Raspberry Pi [Pi2] running XBMC which I think is also based on Debian.

I have set up 3 port forwarding rules at the router and can now connect to ReadyNas & Pi1 without issue over the web.

Pi2 is not contactable, connection refused. I have re-pointed the rule which works for the ReadyNas to Pi2, and it still doesn't work leading me to believe it is a problem on the Pi. I have tried both port 22 (SSH) & 8001 (web server)

Internally I can connect to Pi2 with no issues.

The service I am most concerned about is SSH on port 22 which has been used for most of my testing. Ultimately I'll be wanting to forward webserver ports as well.

What could be wrong?

Comment: What service are you trying to connect to on your second pi?

Comment: Tried SSH port 22 and a webserver port 8001

Comment: Can you access any website from Pi2?

Comment: Is openSSH installed on the second pi? You say it's an XBMC installation, is it openelec or Raspbmc or something like that?

Comment: iptables rules on pi2?

Comment: When you say "Internally I can connect to Pi2 with no issues." you mean you can ssh for example from Pi1 to Pi2 ? If so, there may be some AllowUsers rule in sshd_config to restrict access, or iptables rule.

Comment: Thanks all! 

1. Yes can access web without restriction
2. dpkg --get-selections lists "openssh-blacklist" "openssh-blacklist-extra" and "openssh-client"
3. It's Raspbmc
4. iptables, i'll be looknig at that next
5. Yes, that's correct. I'll check MariusMatutiae's answer below and then cmoe back to that

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your firewall rules on the XMBC Pi. The reason is that, out of security cocerns, some preconfigured boxes bar all connections originating from outside one's LAN.

The command to do this is

```
  iptables -t filter -L -n -v
```

and likewise for the other tables, *nat* and *mangle*. If you can act on these rules, then this is the simplest solution.

Alternatively, if your router runs software like dd-wrt, OpenWrt, Tomato, and so on, then the following rule **on the router**

```
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o LAN_IFACE -s ! 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.15 -p tcp --dport 22 -j MASQUERADE
```

This assumes that your home net is 192.168.0.0/24, that the recalcitrant Pi is 192.168.0.15, and that the router's LAN interface is called LAN_IFACE. The rule simply rewrites the packet's origin as coming from the router itself (192.168.0.1 under the above assumptions), thus tricking the XMBC to think that the connections are initiated locallly, rather than remotely.

Lastly, if your router does **not** allow the above, if you have some other Linux machine (like, I presume, the first Pi), you can

1. port forward the connections for the Pi2 to some high-numbered ports of Pi1
2. redirect these packets, after masquerading, to Pi2 and its proper port.

This time, per port, you need two commands: let us again consider ssh, and let us say that the router has port-forwarded ssh connections for Pi2 to Pi1's 51111 port (192.168.0.10:51111). Then:

```
  iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 51111 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.15:22
  iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.0.15 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Just make sure you have allowed forwarding on Pi1,

```
  sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding=1
```

Comment: There was a rule "dropping" any connections from outside the local network. Thanks for your help